# XGBoost: How to calculate leaf weights in multi-class classification

Tags: xgboost, multiclass-classification, xgbclassifier

I have trouble understanding how XGBoost calculates the leaf weights in multi-class classification.

I generated a simple example with two features and 3 classes.
The training data looks like this:

|  | feature 0 | feature 1 | label y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| x2 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| x3 | 3 | 1 | 2 |

From what I have read so far, XGBoost uses a "one vs. all" principle. Therefore, XGBoost creates separate trees for each class. With a setting of 2 boosting rounds, XGBoost creates 6 trees. The first tree corresponds to class 0, the second to class 1, the third to class 2, the fourth to class 0 and so on ...

I used the following python code to plot the first tree trees.

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier, plot_tree
import numpy as np

X_train = np.array([[1,1],[2,3],[3,1]])
y_train = np.array([0,1,2])

param = {
    'max_depth': 2,
    'eta': 0.3,
    'objective': 'multi:softprob', 
    'num_class': 3, 
    'min_child_weight': 0,
    'n_estimators' : 2,
    'base_score': 0.5
}

clf = XGBClassifier(**param)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

plot_tree(clf, num_trees=0)
plot_tree(clf, num_trees=1)
plot_tree(clf, num_trees=2)
```

The result looks like this: [first tree booster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ss1vU.png)

The question is how the weights of the leaves are calculated?

My thoughts so far: 
As I understand it, XGBoost uses the log loss function for binary classification. 
L(p,y) = −( ylog(p) + (1−y)log(1−p) ) 
(where p= 1/(1+exp(-x)))) 
y is the true label and p is the probability prediction of the model that the sample belongs to class 1. 
The gradient and hessian of this loss function are: 
gradient: p - y 
hessian: p(1-p)

There is a nice explanation of how the ideal weight is calculated for a fixed tree structure ([XGBoost Docs](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/model.html)). Accordingly, the ideal weight is calculated by: 
w_t = - G_t / (H_t + lambda) 
where G_t is the sum of gradient statistics of all samples belonging to the leaf. Similarly, H_t is the sum of second-order statistics (the hessian) of all samples belonging to the leaf.

Now I would like to calculate the weights of the [first tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ss1vU.png). The initial prediction score of all instances shut be 0.5. Since this tree corresponds to class 0 the true labels shut be y1=1, y2=0, y3=0 (since only sample 1 has class 0).
The gradient and hessian statistics are: 
g1 = 0.5 - 1 = -0.5 
g2 = 0.5 - 0 = 0.5
g3 = 0.5 - 0 = 0.5

h1 = 0.5(1-0.5) = 0.25 
h2 = 0.5(1-0.5) = 0.25 
h3 = 0.5(1-0.5) = 0.25

The [first tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ss1vU.png) has only one split criterion f0 < 1.5. Therefore sample 1 is assigned to the left leaf and samples 2 and 3 are assigned to the right leaf.

The weights shut be calculated by:
w1 = - g1 / (h1 + lambda) * eta = 0.5 / (0.25 + 1) * 0.3 = 0.12 
w2 =  - (g2 + g3) / (h2 + h3 + lambda) * eta = -(0.5 +0.5) / (0.25 + 0.25 + 1) * 0.3 = - 0.1998 
with eta the learning rate

My results do not match with the result of XGBoost, since w1 and w2 should be approximately 0.1384 and -0.106.

What am I doing wrong?

I think my real problem is that I do not understand the log loss and how the sigmoid function influences the result.

I would be very grateful if someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake, actually, there are two mistakes:

1. The hessian is wrong: `2*p(1-p)`
2. The prediction score are normalized by the softmax function -> `exp(0.5) / (3 * exp(0.5) = 0.33`

g1 = 0.33 - 1 = -0.67 
g2 = g3 = 0.33 - 0 = 0.33
h1 = h2 = h3 = 2 * 0.33 (1 - 0.33) = 0.4422

w1 = - (-0.67) / (0.4422 + 1 ) * 0.3 = 0.139
w2 = -(0.33 + 0.33) / (0.4422 + 0.4422 + 1) * 0.3 = -0.105

Comment: It would be nice to understand why the softmax is used. Is there any good literature about that?